# How to close my drop down menu in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

My drop down menu opens in mobile view, but when clicking to close, nothing happens.

I've looked at the JS and examples online on what could be wrong but still cant figure it out. Also not sure which js query needs to be udpated as there are 3 different ones; accordion, collapse and 1.112.min.

[Screenshot of dropdown menu error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XBDo.png)

Code:

```
 <!-- navbar menu -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                  
                            <li><a href="our-story">Our Story</a></li>
                             <li class="dropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Solutions</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu"> 
  <li><a href="pos">Point of Sale (POS)</a></li>
  <li><a href="reporting">Business Intelligence &amp; Reporting </a></li>
  <li><a href="integrations">Integrations</a></li>

        </ul>

       </li>
                            <li><a href="customers">Our Customers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="whats-new">What's New</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
                                                </ul>

                    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

jquery collapse

```
(function($) {

  // Constructor
  function Collapse (el, options) {
    options = options || {};
    var _this = this,
      query = options.query || "> :even";

    $.extend(_this, {
      $el: el,
      options : options,
      sections: [],
      isAccordion : options.accordion || false,
      db : options.persist ? jQueryCollapseStorage(el.get(0).id) : false
    });

    // Figure out what sections are open if storage is used
    _this.states = _this.db ? _this.db.read() : [];

    // For every pair of elements in given
    // element, create a section
    _this.$el.find(query).each(function() {
      new jQueryCollapseSection($(this), _this);
    });

    // Capute ALL the clicks!
    (function(scope) {
      _this.$el.on("click", "[data-collapse-summary] " + (scope.options.clickQuery || ""),
        $.proxy(_this.handleClick, scope));

      _this.$el.bind("toggle close open",
        $.proxy(_this.handleEvent, scope));

    }(_this));
  }

  Collapse.prototype = {
    handleClick: function(e, state) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var state = state || "toggle"
      var sections = this.sections,
        l = sections.length;
      while(l--) {
        if($.contains(sections[l].$summary[0], e.target)) {
          sections[l][state]();
          break;
        }
      }
    },
    handleEvent: function(e) {
      if(e.target == this.$el.get(0)) return this[e.type]();
      this.handleClick(e, e.type);
    },
    open: function(eq) {
      if(isFinite(eq)) return this.sections[eq].open();
      $.each(this.sections, function(i, section) {
        section.open();
      })
    },
    close: function(eq) {
      if(isFinite(eq)) return this.sections[eq].close();
      $.each(this.sections, function(i, section) {
        section.close();
      })
    },
    toggle: function(eq) {
      if(isFinite(eq)) return this.sections[eq].toggle();
      $.each(this.sections, function(i, section) {
        section.toggle();
      })
    }
  };

  // Section constructor
  function Section($el, parent) {

    if(!parent.options.clickQuery) $el.wrapInner('<a href="#"/>');

    $.extend(this, {
      isOpen : false,
      $summary : $el.attr("data-collapse-summary",""),
      $details : $el.next(),
      options: parent.options,
      parent: parent
    });
    parent.sections.push(this);

    // Check current state of section
    var state = parent.states[this._index()];

    if(state === 0) {
      this.close(true)
    }
    else if(this.$summary.is(".open") || state === 1) {
      this.open(true);
    } else {
      this.close(true)
    }
  }

  Section.prototype = {
    toggle : function() {
      this.isOpen ? this.close() : this.open();
    },
    close: function(bypass) {
      this._changeState("close", bypass);
    },
    open: function(bypass) {
      var _this = this;
      if(_this.options.accordion && !bypass) {
        $.each(_this.parent.sections, function(i, section) {
          section.close()
        });
      }
      _this._changeState("open", bypass);
    },
    _index: function() {
      return $.inArray(this, this.parent.sections);
    },
    _changeState: function(state, bypass) {

      var _this = this;
      _this.isOpen = state == "open";
      if($.isFunction(_this.options[state]) && !bypass) {
        _this.options[state].apply(_this.$details);
      } else {
        _this.$details[_this.isOpen ? "show" : "hide"]();
      }

      _this.$summary.toggleClass("open", state != "close")
      _this.$details.attr("aria-hidden", state == "close");
      _this.$summary.attr("aria-expanded", state == "open");
      _this.$summary.trigger(state == "open" ? "opened" : "closed", _this);
      if(_this.parent.db) {
        _this.parent.db.write(_this._index(), _this.isOpen);
      }
    }
  };

  // Expose in jQuery API
  $.fn.extend({
    collapse: function(options, scan) {
      var nodes = (scan) ? $("body").find("[data-collapse]") : $(this);
      return nodes.each(function() {
        var settings = (scan) ? {} : options,
          values = $(this).attr("data-collapse") || "";
        $.each(values.split(" "), function(i,v) {
          if(v) settings[v] = true;
        });
        new Collapse($(this), settings);
      });
    }
  });

  //jQuery DOM Ready
  $(function() {
    $.fn.collapse(false, true);
  });

  // Expose constructor to
  // global namespace
  jQueryCollapse = Collapse;
  jQueryCollapseSection = Section;

})(window.jQuery);
```

jquery accordion

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.accordion = function (options) {

        //firewalling
        if (!this || this.length < 1) {
            return this;
        }

        initialize(this, options);

    };

    //create the initial accordion
    function initialize(obj, options) {

        //build main options before element iteration
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.accordion.defaults, options);

        //store any opened default values to set cookie later
        var opened = '';

        //iterate each matched object, bind, and open/close
        obj.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            saveOpts($this, opts);

            //bind it to the event
            if (opts.bind == 'mouseenter') {
                $this.bind('mouseenter', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    toggle($this, opts);
                });
            }

            //bind it to the event
            if (opts.bind == 'mouseover') {
                $this.bind('mouseover', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    toggle($this, opts);
                });
            }

            //bind it to the event
            if (opts.bind == 'click') {
                $this.bind('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    toggle($this, opts);
                });
            }

            //bind it to the event
            if (opts.bind == 'dblclick') {
                $this.bind('dblclick', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    toggle($this, opts);
                });
            }

            //initialize the panels
            //get the id for this element
            id = $this.attr('id');

            //if not using cookies, open defaults
            if (!useCookies(opts)) {
                //close it if not defaulted to open
                if (id != opts.defaultOpen) {
                    $this.addClass(opts.cssClose);
                    opts.loadClose($this, opts);
                } else { //its a default open, open it
                    $this.addClass(opts.cssOpen);
                    opts.loadOpen($this, opts);
                    opened = id;
                }
            } else { //can use cookies, use them now
                //has a cookie been set, this overrides default open
                if (issetCookie(opts)) {
                    if (inCookie(id, opts) === false) {
                        $this.addClass(opts.cssClose);
                        opts.loadClose($this, opts);
                    } else {
                        $this.addClass(opts.cssOpen);
                        opts.loadOpen($this, opts);
                        opened = id;
                    }
                } else { //a cookie hasn't been set open defaults
                    if (id != opts.defaultOpen) {
                        $this.addClass(opts.cssClose);
                        opts.loadClose($this, opts);
                    } else { //its a default open, open it
                        $this.addClass(opts.cssOpen);
                        opts.loadOpen($this, opts);
                        opened = id;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        //now that the loop is done, set the cookie
        if (opened.length > 0 && useCookies(opts)) {
            setCookie(opened, opts);
        } else { //there are none open, set cookie
            setCookie('', opts);
        }

        return obj;
    }
    ;

    //load opts from object
    function loadOpts($this) {
        return $this.data('accordion-opts');
    }

    //save opts into object
    function saveOpts($this, opts) {
        return $this.data('accordion-opts', opts);
    }

    //hides a accordion panel
    function close(opts) {
        opened = $(document).find('.' + opts.cssOpen);
        $.each(opened, function () {
            //give the proper class to the linked element
            $(this).addClass(opts.cssClose).removeClass(opts.cssOpen);
            opts.animateClose($(this), opts);
        });
    }

    //opens a accordion panel
    function open($this, opts) {
        close(opts);
        //give the proper class to the linked element
        $this.removeClass(opts.cssClose).addClass(opts.cssOpen);

        //open the element
        opts.animateOpen($this, opts);

        //do cookies if plugin available
        if (useCookies(opts)) {
            // split the cookieOpen string by ","
            id = $this.attr('id');
            setCookie(id, opts);
        }
    }

    //toggle a accordion on an event
    function toggle($this, opts) {
        // close the only open item
        if ($this.hasClass(opts.cssOpen))
        {
            close(opts);
            //do cookies if plugin available
            if (useCookies(opts)) {
                // split the cookieOpen string by ","
                setCookie('', opts);
            }
            return false;
        }
        close(opts);
        //open a closed element
        open($this, opts);
        return false;
    }

    //use cookies?
    function useCookies(opts) {
        //return false if cookie plugin not present or if a cookie name is not provided
        if (!$.cookie || opts.cookieName == '') {
            return false;
        }

        //we can use cookies
        return true;
    }

    //set a cookie
    function setCookie(value, opts)
    {
        //can use the cookie plugin
        if (!useCookies(opts)) { //no, quit here
            return false;
        }

        //cookie plugin is available, lets set the cookie
        $.cookie(opts.cookieName, value, opts.cookieOptions);
    }

    //check if a accordion is in the cookie
    function inCookie(value, opts)
    {
        //can use the cookie plugin
        if (!useCookies(opts)) {
            return false;
        }

        //if its not there we don't need to remove from it
        if (!issetCookie(opts)) { //quit here, don't have a cookie
            return false;
        }

        //unescape it
        cookie = unescape($.cookie(opts.cookieName));

        //is this value in the cookie arrray
        if (cookie != value) { //no, quit here
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    //check if a cookie is set
    function issetCookie(opts)
    {
        //can we use the cookie plugin
        if (!useCookies(opts)) { //no, quit here
            return false;
        }

        //is the cookie set
        if ($.cookie(opts.cookieName) == null) { //no, quit here
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // settings
    $.fn.accordion.defaults = {
        cssClose: 'accordion-close', //class you want to assign to a closed accordion header
        cssOpen: 'accordion-open', //class you want to assign an opened accordion header
        cookieName: 'accordion', //name of the cookie you want to set for this accordion
        cookieOptions: {//cookie options, see cookie plugin for details
            path: '/',
            expires: 7,
            domain: '',
            secure: ''
        },
        defaultOpen: '', //id that you want opened by default
        speed: 'slow', //speed of the slide effect
        bind: 'click', //event to bind to, supports click, dblclick, mouseover and mouseenter
        animateOpen: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideDown with custom function
            elem.next().stop(true, true).slideDown(opts.speed);
        },
        animateClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideUp with custom function
            elem.next().stop(true, true).slideUp(opts.speed);
        },
        loadOpen: function (elem, opts) { //replace the default open state with custom function
            elem.next().show();
        },
        loadClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the default close state with custom function
            elem.next().hide();
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Post the code please, what do you have, the error etc

Comment: As @Elias said if you post the code then the chances of getting an solution will be high.

Comment: Kindly post the code, so it will be helpful to answer.

Comment: Thank you, code posted.